# Sending ajax requests to a server, that sits above the public folder

Tags: php, apache, reactjs, webpack

I'm starting a full-stack project using React(bundled with Webpack) and PHP(with Apache configured to redirect all requests to the public folder).
I do not want the API to sit on a different host, but rather have it sitting in the same project, **above** the public folder(along side the src folder of React).

The thing is, that i do not know how to use **relative** paths in my AJAX requests, being that the root of the React project is actually the public folder.

For instance, let's assume that i have an "api" folder above the public folder, and i perform this request from React:

```
fetch('/api/product/1/edit')
```

I will get a 404 error, being that the root is interpreted as the public folder, so the ajax would actually go to `/public/api/product/1/edit`, which of course doesn't exist.

Obviously i could use absolute paths(like "http://localhost/project/api/product/1/edit"), but this would force me to create some environment variables, to distinguish localhost from the production server, and this option isn't preferable. Also i wouldn't go for the option of keeping the "api" folder within the public one, because it defeats the whole purpose of a publicly accessible folder.

How would one approach this issue?

Comment: `fetch('/full_server/system_path/to/api/product/1/edit') `

Comment: Try to use  `fetch(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + 'api/product/1/edit')`